# displaying text property for ToolStripTextBox added runtime

Tags: c#, menustrip

I have added a `menustrip` at run time in my application.

```
MenuStrip MS = new MenuStrip();
ToolStripMenuItem MN1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("&New");
```

I am further adding a textbox with an eventhandler for keyup event.

```
ToolStripTextBox qry = new ToolStripTextBox();
qry.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tools23);

public void tools23(Object sender,KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(e.KeyValue ==13)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(the text entered in the toolstriptextbox);
    }
```

How do I display the textbox contents when the event is raised, since i cannot access the text property for runtime controls added?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       public void tools23(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 13)
            {
                ToolStripTextBox t = (ToolStripTextBox)sender;
                MessageBox.Show("the text entered in the toolstriptextbox is " + t.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks , just did the trick, can you guide me to the reference on MSDN for this line code (ToolStripTextBox)sender;

Comment: Basically the first parameter of the event handler (here sender of type object) is the reference to the control from which the event got invoked (in you example it is ToolStripTextBox). This might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983610%28v=vs.71%29.aspx